# How to restart / reload GeoNode

Tags: geonode

Is there a command or interface where I can restart GeoNode or reload GeoNode settings?
Is it even necessary or are the settings (in geonode/settings.py) loaded instantly?

Comment: Do you mean is there a mechanism by which they are automatically loaded, once changed?

Comment: I do. Or any option to make it manually. I made some changes in settings.py, but it doesn't seem to be applied.

Comment: did you try to restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'am afraid that there is a problem somewhere else, but it would be another question. Still, I wanted to know the restart / reload command and settings changes handling.

Answer (score 1):

even though this question is old I stumbled upon it through a google search, and found the answer elsewhere (and way later):

use the following command in the ubuntu shell:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

to restart apache and get the settings.py reloaded.

Comment: Yes, this question is 3 days old :-)

Comment: This shell command restarts the whole Apache server. See the comments under the question, about restarting Apache. It works, but it doesn't seem to be necessary. I think settings.py is reloaded automatically.

Comment: If you make changes in local_settings.py (/etc/geonode) you have to restart Apache (run this command) to apply them